# Python getting 2 sets of data into a JSON object for ajax response

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I am working on a script at the moment, that makes 2 database queries via ajax, the code looks like this,

```
if(request.args.get('staff')):
    data = []
    sel = select('*').select_from(staff).where(staff.c.approver == 1).where(staff.c.workbase == request.args.get('set_workbase')).where((staff.c.status != 'Left') & (staff.c.status != 'Name Changed'))
    approvers = FlaskApp.db_connect().execute(sel).fetchall()
    approvers = [utils.rowdict(a) for a in approvers]
    data['approvers'] = approvers

    sel = select('*').select_from(staff).where(staff.c.name == request.args.get('staff'))
    staff_member = FlaskApp.db_connect().execute(sel).fetchall()
    staff_member = [utils.rowdict(a) for a in staff_member]
    data['staff_member'] = staff_member

    return jsonify(data=data)
```

As you can see, I am running 2 queries, and putting the results into an array, so I can have to both datasets in my response.  However I currently this error message returned in my Ajax reponse.

> TypeError
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You declared `data` as a `list`, so you can not use `data['staff_member']`. What you can do in your case is to make `data` a `dictionary` like:

```
data = {}
```

In Python, to read an element from a `list`, you need to use `my_list[i]`, `i` is an indice of type `int`.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(my_list[0])  # Output: 1
```

To read an element from a `dictionary`, you need to use `my_dict[k]`, `k` is a key of type `string` or any other `immutable` type:

```
my_dict = {'a': 'hello', 'b': 'world'}
print(my_dict['a'])  # Output: hello
```